# I want to request a variable address

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

**I wrote the following command in my own program but it was wrong**

```
    @GET("top-headlines?sources="+"{source}"+"&apiKey=***")
    fun getnewssource(@Path("source") sourceID:String):Call<ModelsResponse>
```

Error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "sources={source}&apiKey=***" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

**I want to send a different source address every time**

Comment: Use `@Query` instead of `@Path`.

Comment: Then I have a parameter to send to that address which is not true

I want to change that address myself

Comment: `source` and `apiKey` is the parameter you want to get from server?

Comment: Yes. I looked at Retrofit's own description. It's written the same way, but it doesn't work. [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: That's different. The link you sent me is to create a dynamic url. But yours is sending two parameters to server side. Check my answer.

Comment: I try this. It does not work

Comment: What you mean by does not work? Still getting same error?

Comment: No, but when I send the parameters with the **`@Query`** or **`@Field`** command, it returns the Status 200 but doesn't have any data inside it.
Here is the API instruction that you need to submit to the Request Source Address to get different sources.
Now the code I wrote is okay, but I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Status 200 mean you have successfully get the response from server. Did you see response in log?

Comment: Yes I did but this body was null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work. You should add Query instead of Path.

```
@GET("top-headlines")
     fun getnewssource(@Query("sources") sourceID:String,
                       @Query("apiKey") apiKey:String):Call<ModelsResponse>
```

Comment: Then I have a parameter to send to that address which is not true

I want to change that address myself

Comment: Which parameter? you can send req body or fields also with query if needed.

Comment: For example, the address should change as follows:
`top-headlines? sources = bbc-news & apiKey = ***`

Comment: So, this answer will work as you can call this API with different "sources".

Comment: Thanks for helping you. I also tried this one you sent. It doesn't work